# JWTAuthenticator and how it modifies the value of the routes

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, silhouette

I'm working in an implemenentation of authenticator with token using the JWTAuthenticator of Silhouette. For the sake of simplicity I decided to adapt the Silhouette Slick Seed Template which constitutes a very nice example for getting started. Making some slight changes in the code (I've followed Silhouette Angular Seed Template) I got an issue after the following code line

```
 env.authenticatorService.init(authenticator).flatMap { v =>
```

...
It seems  like this implemented method "init" is the responsible of changing the value of some
val result = Redirect(routes.ApplicationController.index())
to a proper route, like 
"GET /" in this case.
When I run the JWTAuthenticator version I got the value
Result(303, Map(Location -> /)) instead! (for the route defined in index)

Playing a little bit with the code in the authenticate definition (CredentialsAuthController.scala) you get this kind of Result(303, Map(Location -> /)) anywhere before the init method... So its like this "init" function allows you to get a proper route to redirect to. Is that correct?.
So in basis of these results, my question is:
Why after applying this init function doesn't give me the proper route?

If you are interested in the question please take a look to the jwtimpl branch at

https://github.com/renexdev/Silhouette-Slick-Seed-pg-jwt

Thanks for your time,
ReneX

Answer (score 0):

So far its like the JWTAutheticator doesnt persist the authenticator. See the full discussion at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-silhouette/hKg0ThjUEAI. I'll turn to Silhouette Angular Seed Template to use JWTAuthenticator. Thanks akkie!